# How to obtain Printed Output in R?

Tags: r

I have a function called `filter_output` in `R` which, when evaluated, gives the following output:

```
Smoothed values of states and standard errors at time n = 392:
          Estimate               Std. Error           
Kappa     0.000000003006008509   0.000001266168236651
Phi      -0.000000005332550866   0.000001592969577779
custom1   0.007754099549102765   0.001189674872696318
custom2   0.000000000029421272   0.000614394025071959
```

The problem however is that there's no way for me to store these values in a separate matrix - for example, I can't use `filter_output$...` or `filter_output[1]` etc. to obtain the estimates or standard error since they don't appear to be a part of any call of the function (it's not in a list either).

I've tried using the function `capture.output` in order to obtain these individual values but this function appears to extract them as strings, which seems to be computationally inefficient since I have to split up the string and then convert it to a numeric value. Is there a quick and efficient way for me to store values when they're outputted?

Answer (score 0):

Just type the name of the opbject you have saved it as

```
filter_output1 <- filter_output %>% select(Estimate, Std. Error)

#print
filter_output1
```